# Paypal button problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a PayPal Button tested in sandbox environment and it worked. Now i am trying to get it working in the live environment the button remains disable.

My code is

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];  
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getInstance] getPayButton:self buttonType:BUTTON_278x43 startCheckOut:@selector(payWithPayPal) PaymentType:DONATION withLeft:20 withTop:240];   
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

if I change Environment  ENV_LIVE to ENV_SANDBOX  the button is  enable

Comment: I wonder whether that paypal app id is supposed to be a secret info or not...

Comment: I believe the ID he is using is a sample Test App ID.

Comment: Hey Rams, I am integrating PayPal in my iphone application with sandbox environment but I am getting Network Timeout error and also I have noticed that Paypal Object is also not initialised.....Can you please help me.... For Initialisation I have used this code -- [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];  I will wait for your reply...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to submit the app to paypal before converting it to live. They will provide you one id after testing your app in sandbox mode.

Check this link

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep

Answer (score 2):

At times, when PayPal server is down or for any problems with server, the initialization of the PayPal object fails, and the button would be disabled in these cases.

You can check for the status of the initialization using the following code:

```
if ([PayPal initializationStatus] == STATUS_COMPLETED_SUCCESS) { //We have successfully initialized and are ready to pay
}

}
```

From the documentation:

> The “Pay with PayPal” button returned
>   by the getPayButtonWithTarget method
>   is disabled till the initialization is
>   complete. Once the initialization is
>   complete, if it was successful, the
>   button will become enabled.
>
> When initialization status returns
>   STATUS_COMPLETED_ERROR - Request
>   timeouts or host unavailable (Network
>   connection failure) are valid
>   initialization error cases for
>   initializePayPal  retry attempts.
>
> If initialization failed due to a
>   buyer error, the error message is
>   presented as a UIAlertView.

Comment: So who do you call when this condition is consistently failing and indicating that there is a problem with the server? Can you hint at what the best path into PayPal for this is?

Answer (score 2):

The live environment can be used only after your app has been approved by PayPal. The AppID you are using to initialize PayPal is hardcoded for use in the SANDBOX env. For a live application you need to use the App ID that is assigned to your app by PayPal. Follow the [steps in this page](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/apps101) to get an App ID for your app.

Remember, you need to have your own verified [PayPal Premier or Business Account](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/gen/personal_vs_business-outside&bn_r=m#special) before the app will work (even if it is approved).

If you are submitting a mobile app take these extra steps

1. iPhone (iOS) app must include:

   - ".app" and "mobile provision" file with UDIDs **396ea30899bb294607270258115a8eb9c929c021** AND **7754a0e4b281fd313f20d9e13c87534e26b091e3**. Those are the two iPhones that PayPal will test with.
2. iPad (iOS) app must include:

   - ".app" and "mobile provision" file with UDID **92e19f163eb553d42dfed00487fcaf73f7521c6e**
3. For an Android app, provide a link to your .apk file or attach the .apk file in the "Screen captures and any supporting documentation" of the application
4. For a Blackberry app, provide a link to your .jad file or attach the .jad file in the "Screen captures and any supporting documentation" of the application
5. For a Symbian app, provide a link to your .wgz file or attach the .wgz file in the "Screen captures and any supporting documentation" of the application

Once your app is approved, you'll receive a Live App ID. Just replace the Test App ID with the Live App ID, and change your Sandbox API credentials to Live API Credentials.